# Showing items and categories after clicking on a subcategory

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin

How can I speed up my app?  It's very slow if I click on a button and open a new page. All data in time is local. I'm not sure if the problem is in my code or xamarinu.

```
foreach (var category in avm.Categories) 
    {
        ToolbarItem ItemCategory = new ToolbarItem();
        ItemCategory.Name = category.Name;
        ToolbarItems.Add (ItemCategory);
        ItemCategory.Activated += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            SubCategoryStack.Children.Clear();
            this.IsPresented = true;
            foreach (var Subcategory in category.SubCategories) 
            {
                Button btn_subcategory = new Button();
                btn_subcategory.Text = Subcategory.Name;
                SubCategoryStack.Children.Add(btn_subcategory);

                btn_subcategory.Clicked += (object senderr, EventArgs d) => 
                {   
                    this.IsPresented= false;
                    stackIbro2.Children.Clear();
                    stackIbro.Children.Clear();
                    Array array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Article), Subcategory.Articles.Count);
                    for(int i = 0; i< Subcategory.Articles.Count; i++)
                    {
                        StackLayout articlesH = new StackLayout()
                        {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal};
                        Button btn_article = new Button();
                        Label btn_Quantity = new Label();
                        array.SetValue(Subcategory.Articles[i], i);
                        btn_article.Text = Subcategory.Articles[i].Name;
                        btn_Quantity.Text = Subcategory.Articles[i].Quantity.ToString();

                        btn_article.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                        btn_Quantity.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                        articlesH.Children.Add(btn_article);
                        articlesH.Children.Add(btn_Quantity);
                        stackIbro2.Children.Add(articlesH);
                    }


                    //btn_article.Text = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Article> ((Article[])array).ToString();

                };


            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: My idea is if a user clicks on a subcategory that his items and categories display on the page. Problem is if subcategory have 60 article or more

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

Assuming you or **Mr.Maintainer** will have to fix a bug in this code in 3 months, will you still know what any of these variables

- avm
- stackIbro2
- stackIbro
- articlesH

should do or represent ?

You should give your objects/variables meaningful names so that you or **Mr.Maintainer** will see at the first glance what to expect.

**Indentation**

> ```
>                     StackLayout articlesH = new StackLayout()
>                     {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal};
> ```

here it can be missed at first glance that these 2 lines belong together. You should indent them like

```
                    StackLayout articlesH = new StackLayout()
                        {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal};
```

**btn_subcategory.Clicked eventhandler**

- Grouping together the related code, will increase readability.
- the `Array array` is not really needed at all, you can remove it
- commented code is dead code, hence it should be removed.
- changing the `for` loop to a `for each` loop will add readability
- `EventArgs` are name `e` and it is `sender` instead of `senderr`
- don't use hungarian notation (at least like you have done). If the type changes but you forget to change the name also you get weird code like: `Label btn_Quantity`

  ```
  btn_subcategory.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
  {   
      this.IsPresented= false;
      stackIbro2.Children.Clear();
      stackIbro.Children.Clear();

      foreach (Article article in Subcategory.Articles)
      {
          StackLayout articlesH = new StackLayout()
              {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal};

          Button button = new Button()
              {
                  Text = article.Name,
                  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
              }

          Label label = new Label()
              {
                  Text = article.Quantity.ToString(),
                  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
              }

          articlesH.Children.Add(button;
          articlesH.Children.Add(label);
          stackIbro2.Children.Add(articlesH);
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: Is naming still an issue if it's **Mrs.Maintainer** fixing the bugs? ;)

Comment: The naming is not a problem because today I wrote this just to test the speed, the problem is xamarin, which we very slowly draws more than 30 button